# IOS Compiler unexplained Changes/Errors

Tags: swift, xcode6

I have two Apps that I developed in January 2015 to March 2015. I went on vacation with my Laptop (Macbook Pro) and never touched Xcode (6.3.2) developer software - or my apps which still work on my iPhone 4/5/6 and iPad, but I did update my developer licence as per Apple just a few days ago via their website.

Today June 11, 2015 I loaded Xcode and both apps for the first time and I am getting errors down casting such as

> Did you mean to use as! to force downcast?

and other compile errors for a total of 77 Red Flag Errors.

I have cleaned/build folder, restarted Xcode/laptop, tried attempting to fix the errors, but stopped (undid everything) because it was working before.

Can someone tell me if anything in the software could have changed or what is happening so I can fix it?

Comment: Are you sure Xcode didn't automatically update, updating the Swift compiler with it?

Comment: That very much looks like the changes that were introduced with Swift 1.2/Xcode 6.3 (documented in the Xcode release notes) . Did you try "Update to latest Swift syntax" in Xcode?  There also are some questions about exactly the same error message.

Comment: cocoa frameworks got better tagging for swift.

Comment: All: XCODE says last modified Sunday, May 31, 2015 at 12:13 PM but the checkbox to update automatically is unchecked. There are components and documentation that seem to be waiting to download. Where do I "Update to latest Swift syntax"?

Comment: @PaulHolness: Edit -> Convert -> To latest Swift syntax ...

Comment: @MartinR: Thanks fix many errors, I am sifting through the rest - I still don't have a solid answer yet, but will mark the answer when compiled and tested + thanks!